# appengineRun fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/ApiProxyLocal

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I have based a new project upon https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java but I get the error (se below) when I run it locally. I.e. the task **appengineRun** fails so I wonder what dependence that I am missing.

```
Varning: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@c9eb8b5: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/ApiProxyLocal
maj 14, 2014 11:59:31 FM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn 
Varning: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/ApiProxyLocal
at    com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.init(ServeBlobFilter.java:55)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 29 more
```

Comment: any information about your configuration? How is the sdk being acessed?

Comment: testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.19"

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your classpath - specifically, with appengine-testing.jar. Add it to your classpath if you don't have it there. If you already have it, remove it, refresh the project, and then add it again. Note that you don't need it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Make sure you add this jar from the correct version of App Engine SDK. You can find this jar in (for example):

> appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6/lib/testing/appengine-testing.jar

Comment: I have to add that jar to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder for the local appengine to work even if the project already referenced it as an external jar in it's original location.  I tried also adding the external reference to this jar in the run configuration classpath but that didn't work either.  Only copying the jar worked.

Comment: Why is the dep   testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:$gaeVersion"   ... not enough?

Answer (score 0):

We have two dependencies

- appengine-testing
- appengine-api-stubs

In Maven or Gradle configuration file and **appengine-api-stubs** is conflicting with **appengine-testing** configuration.

By Removing **appengine-api-stubs** Local project running successfully.